# Google Apps Calendar createEvent() creates calendar entries one hour too late

Tags: google-apps-script, timezone-offset

I am trying to implement a seat booking app based on this example: http://collaborative-tools-project.blogspot.ch/search?q=simple+booking

I got it to work, but still have a timezone issue. The code below takes a give date and defines hours and minutes for the start and end date/time of the event.
It works, but every reservation is made one hour too late in the calendar and I do not understand why.
I am living in GMT+1 time zone (Switzerland).

```
var start_date_obj = new Date (date);
  start_date_obj.setHours( start_hours,start_minutes,0,0 );
  var end_date_obj = new Date( date );
  end_date_obj.setHours( end_hours, end_minutes,0,0 );

  var title = "Buchung " + tutor ;

  var calendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById('ondemandmanagement.net_1rc3sl8cfbfr1pp3kekvtb53s4@group.calendar.google.com');
  Logger.log("Start: " + start_date_obj + " End: " + end_date_obj );
  var event = calendar.createEvent(title +": "+email, start_date_obj, end_date_obj, {location: "Galmiz"});
```

The API reference says:

> createEvent(title, startTime, endTime)
>
> Creates a new event. If no time zone is specified, the time values are
>   interpreted in the context of the script's time zone, which may be
>   different than the calendar's time zone.

When I check the log, I see that start_date_obj and end_date_obj are in the correct timezone (GMT+1).
However, the createEvent() call seems to use PDT time zone and the calendar shows the event in GMT+2 or GMT+1 DST (one hour too late).

The extract of the logfile for the code sniplet for an event booking at **10:00 GMT+1**:

Logger.log([Start: Sat Jun 09 2018 **10:00:00 GMT+0100 (BST)** End: Sat Jun 09 2018 **10:20:00 GMT+0100 (BST)**, []]) [0 seconds]
[17-11-18 20:01:58:235 CET] Calendar.createEvent([Buchung Scheibe 3: heinz.ruffieux@ondemandmanagement.net, Sat Jun 09 **02:00:00 PDT** 2018, Sat Jun 09 **02:20:00 PDT** 2018, {location=Galmiz}]) [0.333 seconds]

Whereas 02:00 PDT in fact translates into 11:00 GMT+1 (one hour too late). But I do not understand where it is coming from. Is the BST the problem? Where does it come from?

Can anyone help me with that?

Thanks a lot

Heinz

Comment: BST means British Summer Time, that might actually be the problem, as it adds one hour.

Comment: what is the time zone of the calendar, that you're adding the events to?

Comment: Both the script editor and the calendar have their own time zone.  File -> Project Properties in script editor.  Both the script editor and calendar times zones should update to DST automatically in you are in DST. JavaScript date methods in the script automatically use the script time zone.  Open up your calendar settings to see what the primary time zone is.  If the script and calendar time zones are not the same, then there will be a difference in the hour setting. If you don't need to write to multiple calendars in different time zones then set the script and calendar time zones to be same

Comment: You got it Sandy! It was set tooo....London Standard time! 
In my wildest dreams I would not have come to the idea that the script editor got it's own timezone, given the explanation in the API reference!

Thank you sooo much! 

Heinz